# Get condition operator by EL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, el

I'm using the following code to get condition object by rest api,this object have operator and response fields ,I need to use them in if condition statement like

```
if(response  condition.operator condition.response)
```

condition.operator should be <  ,  > or else ,So how to get condition operator by EL?

Full code

```
Conditions.get({id:id}).$promise.then(function(condition){          
  if(response  condition.operator condition.response){
    console.log("")
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result;
if(condition.operator == '<') {
    result = result < condition.result;
} else if(condition.operator == '>')
    result = result > condition.result;
} else {
    result = result || condition.result;
}

if(result) {
    console.log("");
}
```